# add nested values to associative array - JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

Simply stuck with this one, any help would be appreciated.

I have an associative array like this:

```
var player = {
  source: {
    item1: value,
    item2: value,
    item3: {
      item3-1: value
    }
  },
  playback: {
    parameter1: value,
    parameter2: value,
  }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is add values into player.source like this:

```
player.source.item4.item4-1 = 'something'
```

such that player.source looks like this:

```
  source: {
    item1: value,
    item2: value,
    item3: {
      item3-1: value
    },
    item4: {
      item4-1: 'something',
    },
  },
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: There is no such thing as an "associative array" in JavaScript. What you have is an object, and you're adding properties to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's not lil' bit too overcomplicated, but seems working.

```js
var player = {source:{item1:"value",item2:"value",item3:{"item3-1":"value"}},playback:{parameter1:"value",parameter2:"value"}},
    obj = {
      'item4-1': 'something'
    };

    player.source.item4 = obj;
    console.log(player);
```

Comment: Close.. I want to create a new property 'item4' under 'source' and add properties to it.

Comment: @ymdahi I knew I have overcomplicated it. Fixed.

Comment: awesome, trying this out now

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this - just create a function for generically adding a property/value to an object. If the property already exists, it just overwrites the value.

```js
var value = 5;
var player = {
  source: {
    item1: value,
    item2: value,
    item3: {
      "item3-1": value
    }
  },
  playback: {
    parameter1: value,
    parameter2: value,
  }
}

function addProperty(obj, categoryName, value) {
  obj[categoryName] = value;
  return obj;
}

addProperty(player.source, "item4", addProperty({}, "item4-1", value));
console.log(player);
```

To add subsequent properties/values, you can access the newly created properties on your object like so:

```
addProperty(player.source.item4, "item4-2", 6);
addProperty(player.source.item4, "item4-3", 7);
// etc...
```